# ¿Por qué la diferencia entre el DLE y el DAMER en el término yoyo?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado

Pasando por el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cDJvEHn) (en internet) encontraba que el término yoyo era *exclusivo* de Cuba, México y El Salvador, dando a entender que para el resto del mundo hispano manejamos yoyós... algo bastante raro pues toda mi vida he jugado y visto jugar con yoyos (graves, no agudos) en Colombia. Al ir al [DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=yoyo), el yoyo cubre casi la mitad del mundo hispanohablante y las definiciones (en su primera acepción) que deberían ser iguales, son las siguientes:

DLE (yoyó)

> Juguete de origen chino que consiste en dos discos pequeños unidos por un eje en torno al cual se ata y enrolla una cuerda por la que se lo hace subir y bajar de manera sucesiva a impulsos de la mano.

DAMER (yoyo I. 1.)

> *Mx, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, Cu, RD, PR, Co, Ve, Bo, Py.* Juguete que consiste en dos discos de madera, metal o plástico, unidos por un eje al que se ata una cuerda, que se utiliza agarrando el otro extremo de la cuerda, con los dedos, para sujetarlo, mientras se lanza al aire intentando que se enrolle y se desenrolle sucesivamente.

Si bien la RAE no es la ASALE, no encuentro motivos para cambiar el significado e incluso podrían unificarlos. ¿Existe motivo para mantener la diferencia y desconocer el término grave para casi 120 millones de hispanohablantes en el DLE?

Comment: ¿Qué es la ASALE?

Comment: @Rodrigo La asociación de academias de la lengua española

Comment: valga aclarar que al menos en escrito ha sido más habitual el término grave que el agudo https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yoyo%2Cyoy%C3%B3&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=10&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyoyo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyoy%C3%B3%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Nota que NGrams recoge muchos ejemplos del nombre *Yoyo* también, algo que hace difícil de interpretar aquellos resultados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay algunas explicaciones posibles, pero en principio, la del DAMER es la más nueva.  Para saber por qué tienen una definición diferente, tal vez pensasen que la definición del DLE no era suficiente, tal vez la escribiesen de forma independiente.  La mayoría de las entradas que existen en ambos diccionarios tiene definiciones ligeramente (o no) diferentes.  Principalmente con respecto a las etiquetas (aunque posiblemente hasta cierto punto para la acepción en sí) las razones podrían ser de las siguientes:

1. Según la academia, hubo modificaciones a casi la mitad de las entradas, pero leyendo sobre [los cambios](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/La_vigesimotercera_edicion.pdf), es fácil imaginar que una palabra como *yoyó/yoyo* quedara sin actualización sin que hubiese razón específica.
2. Las entradas del DAMER, como regla general, reconocen usos más minoritarios y localizados de las palabras y si en aquellos países donde tiene uso no es el uso mayoritario (excepto en Méjico, El Salvador y Cuba), puede que hayan pensado mejor solo reconocerlo con los países donde su uso es general y preferente a *yoyó*.

Como ignoro la extensión de *yoyo* frente *yoyó* en aquellos países, no puede decir nada con respecto a n.º 2, pero n.º 1 no me sorprendería en absoluto, ambas formas estaban.

En todo caso, los académicos que se reúnen para mantener y actualizar el DLE, que son los académicos de ASALE de los cuales se incluyen los de la RAE (el DLE la editan y la publican la RAE y la ASALE juntamente), pueden pedir modificaciones y adiciones.  Si recuerdo bien, para la 23.ª edición, se daba preferencia a las cosas que se registraban en tres países o más, por lo que si hubiese sido propuesta la adición de nuevas etiquetas geográficas conforme el DAMER, no veo cómo no habría sido aprobada.